# Getting the UIElement from an animation completed event

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, casting, uielement

From my codebehind I want to start an animation on a specific `UIElement`, when that animation ends I would like to do some other processing on that `UIElement`. I am having trouble figuring out how to convert the `AnimationClock` object that I receive as the sender of an Animation Completed event into the `UIElement` object that the animation was performed on.

Here is the code I use to build and start the animation:

```
DoubleAnimation FadeOutAnim = new DoubleAnimation(1, 0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.5));
FadeOutAnim.Completed += new EventHandler(FadeOutAnim_Completed);

UIElement element = lstMessages.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(sender) as UIElement;
if(element != null)
   element.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, FadeOutAnim);
```

And here is my Completed event where I want access to the `UIElement` again.

```
void FadeOutAnim_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement animation = sender; //This is an AnimationClock and I can't seem to figure out how to get my UIElement back.

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

If the handler is useless (i for one cannot find a way to get the animated element back), you could just raise another event which does contain that information:

```
private event EventHandler FadeAnimationCompleted;
private void OnFadeAnimationCompleted(object sender)
{
    var handler = FadeAnimationCompleted;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(sender, null);
}
```

```
FadeAnimationCompleted += new EventHandler(This_FadeAnimationCompleted);
FadeOutAnim.Completed += (s, _) => OnAnimationCompleted(element);
```

```
void This_FadeAnimationCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Sender is the UIElement
}
```

---

Even easier would be to make a direct method-call in the delegate:

```
FadeOutAnim.Completed += (s, _) => FadeAnimationCompleted(element);
```

```
void FadeAnimationCompleted(UIElement element)
{
    //Meaningful code goes here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Easy and great.